# Multi threading for generating names

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am making artificial intelligence bots for my private server. Their names have to be random and unique, so I made a function that retrieves a random string from a website. it takes a second to generate 3 names and adds them to an arraylist. That means in 10 minutes I get 1800 randomly generated strings.

That is a little bit bad since I need a large amount of names in the shortest time possible, so I made multiple threads that generate those 1800 names in less than a minute. But I am not sure whether this is a good practice or not.

```
public static void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        new Thread("" + i) {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    names.add(NameGenerator.generateRandomName(Utils.random(3, 12)));
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

I don't think that this is efficient nor the best practice.

Edit: (Added functions)

```
public static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

public static String generateRandomName(int length) {
    String result;
    try {
        result = postURL("https://jimpix.co.uk/generators/word-generator.asp#result",
                "go=yes&ul1=0&chars=" + length + "&match=1&numwords=1&alpha=0&lk=", 30000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.logObject("Failed generating a new name");
        return null;
    }
    result = result.substring(result.indexOf("check-username.asp?u=") + "check-username.asp?u=".length(),
            result.indexOf("\"><span style=\"color:white;"));
    return capitalizeFirstLetter(result);
}
```

Comment: What is `names` and is it a thread safe collection?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry for not including that. I have updated my post.

Comment: Can you change the `numwords` parameter in the URL to 1800?

Comment: Other than using thread-safe collection, you also probably want to join all created threads, so you know when you have all results. And probably using web service for such a trivial task is a waste. You would be better off with local solution.

Comment: @zch You are absolutely right! So maybe like a .txt file with names on it?

Comment: The site can generate 50 words at once. Using this is simpler and probably much faster than any threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is not a proper way to use threads. Threads are used to handle such things like running GUI and app logic separately so the GUI will not freeze. They are also used to run separated server's and client's thread. You will not actualy benefit from threads in this example. Also, without using executors you are going to run out of memory because of large number of threads (600 is ok but it should be avoided and limited). Use just one thread to not block your main program or do not use threads at all.

In theory, performance would actualy boost on multicore processor but it depends on multiple factors.

Change your code to something like this:

```
public static void init() {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         for (int i = 0; i < 600 * 3; i++) {
              names.add(NameGenerator.generateName());  
         }
     }
   }).start();
}
```

Also, using this example, remember, that the thread is async so also provide some kind of callback function to get your program noticed if it matters.

Use synchronized collection too.

Comment: Thanks though, really explained well! Just a small question. What about the start() cause I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: i am missing one bracket before .start(); ----- edited

Comment: amm thanks but checking speed, that is still like without using the thread at all. So what is the difference?

Comment: Speed does not matter in your example. It cannot be increased by using threads. Thread in my example only allows you to continue to work with main thread meanwhile the namegenerator thread generates names. So in my example, after 1 call, there would be 2 threads (main and generator) and both would run in parallel. You must know if it is what you want or not. As i said, if it would be by my example then you would need to set up some callback function to notify main thread that namegenerator is done doing its job

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a synchronized structure for your List as you modify it concurrently.
As more efficient alternative, you could create a class implementing `Runnable` and declare in it a `List` field that contains the generated words. Instantiating 3 instances of the class, start them as Thread and merge their `List` result.
You could use `CountDownLatch` from the client side that the started threads will "countDown". It will ease the synchronization step to perform the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate unique, random Strings, you could just use [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). They are randomly-generated unique String in this format: aeb1f910-1340-4f9d-829b-c9e179b21b4e.

You can generate them in Java using the UUID.randomUUID() method.
Granted, they are not readable names, but they should fit your usecase quite well.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want that. I want names for bots/players in in a proper form and not just any strings.